# QlikView saving causes new versions to be created

Tags: business-intelligence, qlikview, qliksense

I have got a QlikView 11 Personal 64 bit edition. As I am trying to learn, I am building simple models.

Each time as I click save its creating a new version of the file. I am not sure why this is happening.

Has any one faced this problem? Is there any setting to deal with this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Qlikview

Settings > User Preferences > Save (tab) > Untick "Use backup"